# DynamoDB - JAVA - BatchWrite with low-level API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm wondering if we can perform Batch Write/Update with low-level API for DynamoDB for java.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Something like this:

```
Map<String, List<WriteRequest>> writeRequestItems = new HashMap<String, List<WriteRequest>>();
Map<String, AttributeValue> userItem1 = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
userItem1.put("userId", new AttributeValue().withS("1"));
userItem1.put("name", new AttributeValue().withS("Alex"));
Map<String, AttributeValue> userItem2 = new HashMap<String,AttributeValue>();
userItem2.put("userId", new AttributeValue().withS("2"));
userItem2.put("name", new AttributeValue().withS("Jonh"));
List<WriteRequest> userList = new ArrayList<WriteRequest>();
userList.add(new WriteRequest().withPutRequest(new PutRequest().withItem(userItem1)));
userList.add(new WriteRequest().withPutRequest(new PutRequest().withItem(userItem2)));
writeRequestItems.put("User", userList);
BatchWriteItemRequest batchWriteItemRequest = new BatchWriteItemRequest(writeRequestItems);
BatchWriteItemResult batchWriteItemResult = dynamoDBClient.batchWriteItem(batchWriteItemRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use AmazonDynamoDB class to perform these operations.

Check http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDB.html#batchWriteItem-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.BatchWriteItemRequest-